# Why do open file handles to deleted files seemingly fill up the hard drive

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

So, to make a long story short, I wrote a (python) program which opened a lot of files, writes data in it, and then deleted the files, but didn't properly close the file handles.
After some time, this program halted due to lack of disk space.

Auto-complete in bash failed with `cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device"`, and `lsof -nP +L1` showed a ton of no-longer existing files.

After killing my program, all the filehandles were closed, disk space was "free" again and everything was fine.

Why did this happen? The disk space wasn't physically filled up. Or is the number of file handles limited?

Comment: kernel has no way to know what you want to do with those open files, discard them ? save them ? trucate and re-write data ? add new data ? so kernel keep them open with their data writen to disk until you either properly delete them or properly save them.

Comment: The system call to delete a file only removes it from the visible file list in the directory, that’s why it is called unlink((). The actual allocated data can only be removed and reclaimed if no handle is open to it. (Or in case of Windows fhe unlink completely fails while busy)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Deleting a file in Unix simply removes a named reference to its data (hence the syscall name `unlink`/`unlinkat`, rather than `delete`). In order for the data itself to be freed, there must be no other references to it. References can be taken in a few ways:

1. There must be no further references to this data on the filesystem (`st_nlink` must be 0) -- this can happen when hard linking. Otherwise, we'd drop the data while there's still a way to access it from the filesystem.
2. There must be no further references to this data from open file handles (on Linux, the relevant `struct file`'s `f_count` in the kernel must be 0). Otherwise, the data could still be accessed or mutated by reading or writing to the file handle (or `/proc/pid/fd` on Linux), and we need somewhere to continue to store it.

Once both of these conditions are fulfilled, the data is eligible to be freed. As your case violates condition #2 -- you still have open file handles -- the data continued to be stored on disk (since it has nowhere else to go) until the file handle was closed.

Some programs even use this in order to simplify cleaning up their data. For example, imagine a program which needs to have some large data stored on disk for intermediate work, but doesn't need to share it with others. If it opens and then immediately deletes that file, it can use it without having to worry about making sure they clean up on exit -- the open file descriptor reference count will naturally drop to 0 on `close(fd)` or exit, and the relevant space will be freed whether the program exits normally or not.

#### Detection

Deleted files which are still being held open by a file descriptor can be found with `lsof`, using something like the following:

```
% lsof -nP +L1
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK      NODE NAME
pulseaudi  1799 cdown    6u   REG    0,1 67108864     0      1025 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
chrome    46460 cdown   45r   REG   0,27   131072     0    105357 /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.gL8tTh (deleted)
```

This lists all open files which an `st_nlink` value of less than one.

#### Mitigation

In your case you were able to close the file handles by terminating the process, which is a good solution if possible.

In cases where that isn't possible, on Linux you can access the data backed by the file descriptor via `/proc/pid/fd` and truncate it to size 0, even if the file has already been deleted:

```
: > "/proc/pid/fd/$num"
```

Note that, depending on what your application then does with this file descriptor, the application may be varying degrees of displeased about having the data changed out from under it like this.

If you are certain that file descriptor has simply leaked and will not be accessed again, then you can also use `gdb` to close it. First, use `lsof -nP +L1` or `ls -l /prod/pid/fd` to find the relevant file descriptor number, and then:

```
% gdb -p pid --batch -ex 'call close(num)'
```

---

To answer your other question, although it's not the cause of your problem:

> Is the number of file [descriptors] limited?

The number of file descriptors *is* limited, but that's not the limit you're hitting here. "No space left on device" is `ENOSPC`, which is what we generate when your filesystem is out of space. If you were hitting a file descriptor limit, you'd receive `EMFILE` (process-level shortage, rendered by `strerror` as "Too many open files") or `ENFILE` (system-level shortage, rendered by `strerror` as "Too many open files in system") instead. The process level soft limit can be inspected with `ulimit -Sn`, and the system-level limit can be viewed at `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`.

Comment: I was making it clear that it works on abnormal exits as well as normal exits.It also means the programmer doesn't have to try to handle all the possible error paths and put in clean up code on them

Answer (score 0):

As long as you hold a handle to the (now deleted) file, you can still access its data (from the process that holds the handle). That data needs a place to live.